# Add string to the 0th index of NSMutablearray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

i have a NSMutableArray "array1 " with 11 elements i want to insert one more string at the first position  how can i do this ?
i tried following code but this throwing exception

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *categoryPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list.plist"];
    categoryList = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:categoryPath];
    NSMutableArray *Name=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
Name=[[categoryList objectForKey:@"catlist"] valueForKey:@"category_name"];
    NSString *str=@"Rahul";
    [categoryName insertObject:str atIndex:0];
```

exception

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8349e30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2465052 0x1738d0a 0x2466ced 0x23cbf00 0x23cbce2 0x6f690 0x6f402 0x96e64e 0x7123c 0x930a5 0x96e64e 0x96dc1c 0x99456d 0x97ed47 0x995441 0x99545d 0x9954f9 0x97f213 0xb24fbd 0xb24ccb 0x9812b7 0x9813df 0x97ed9b 0x995441 0x99545d 0x9954f9 0x8d5d65 0x8d5dac 0x8a6be6 0x8a78a6 0x8b6743 0x8b71f8 0x8aaaa9 0x3922fa9 0x24391c5 0x239e022 0x239c90a 0x239bdb4 0x239bccb 0x8a72a7 0x8a8a9b 0x2f2d 0x2e55 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: Show your code in context. What is "Name" ?

Comment: name is my nsmutable array

Comment: Please show the code allocating the NSMutableArray, the ivar type you are storing it in and when you attempt to insert the object. It feels as though you are trying this on a NSArray instead, hence the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The exception says it all,

**__NSArrayI** is a code-word for an immutable array - that is, a "regular" NSArray which you cannot change.

The **Name** array is not a NSMutableArray for sure.

may be you are assigning a **NSArray** to **NSMutable** array **or** you have initialised the **NSMutableArray *Name as a NSArray**.

**EDIT 1:**

### Problem Solved

*change your code like this,*

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *categoryPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list.plist"];
categoryList = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:categoryPath];
NSMutableArray *Name=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[categoryList objectForKey:@"catlist"] valueForKey:@"category_name"]];
NSString *str=@"Rahul";
[categoryName insertObject:str atIndex:0];
```

Comment: I updated my answer, now check !!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray array];
[array1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", assamElite] atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not NSMutableArray, it is a NSArray that is the exception saying. Check where you create or assign the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a breakpoint before the line that causes the crash and then type in the debugger:

```
po (NSString*)NSStringFromClass([Name class]);
```

This way you can see that **Name** is actually an instance of NSArray.
Even though you allocate an instance of NSMutableArray, you overwrite the pointer in the second line:

```
NSMutableArray *Name=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//this returns an NSArray
Name=[[categoryList objectForKey:@"catlist"] valueForKey:@"category_name"];
```